# textview doesn't wraps correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

[image: Two TextView]

I've two textviews aligned horizontally. when the second TextView becomes longer it wraps to the next line incorrectly. I want it to start the text from the beginning of the layout instead of just below the TextView.

I've tried flow layout but it wrap all the text to the bottom rather than wrapping just the additional text.

[image: FlowLayout]

**What I want :**

[image: What I want photo]

The reason I want two TextView is because I'm working on Drag and Drop quiz, so when the user drags the answer to the textview it will change it's content "setText(answer)" to be the answer.
Thank you for helping
[Drag and drop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWtNg.png)

Comment: did you searched about drag and drop in android?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible. You can always use string with arguments to achieve that.

e.g.

```
<string name="test_string">%1$s %2$s</string>
```

and then

```
getString(R.string.test_string, "text view one text", "text view two text")
```

Comment: The problem is that I should have two TextViews rather than one, becaue I will edit each separatly programmatically.

Comment: The problem with what you want is the textView2 width. You can't have in one line 50 dp with and in the second 100dp for the same textview. You can always keep two different string values in your class and add them using getString() method. Also, if you want to make it fill visually like 2 different textviews, you can use SpannableString().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible. It sounds like an awkward way of going about something quite simple.

My solution would be to have 1 TextView, and join the two strings together that would otherwise be in separate TextViews.

Comment: Thank you for answering Tom, but I'm afraid that I should have two TextViews for a reason :)

Comment: For what purpose? Can you help me understand why 2 in this kind of layout is necessary?

Comment: The reason I want two TextView is because I'm working on Drag and Drop quiz, so when the user drags the answer to the textview it will change it's content "setText(answer)" to be the answer. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two textViews, take two string variables and work on them. in the end, just concatenate two strings and display it in the textView.

In order to give it look and feel of two different textViews, you can either use html format, or spannable text.

We might be able to help understand your problem better if you can explain the actual scenario, and why two textViews are necessary.